# UserForm TextBox Font Size Problems

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, userform

first of all, I hope this question has not been asked befor, I could not find a similar question.

I have a couple of TextBoxes in an UserForm being generated automaticly depending on the amount of rows used in a Excel Sheet. The Text is being pulled from the Cells. That all works without any problems.

```
Private Sub CreateBoxes()
    Dim lastRow As String
    Dim tb_X As MSForms.TextBox
    Dim TopPos As Integer

    lastRow = Sheets("Data").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    TopPos = -15
    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If Sheets("Data").Range("C" & i).Value = "Booking" Then
            Set tb_X = Frame6.Controls.Add("Forms.TextBox.1", "tb_" & i, True)
            TopPos = TopPos + 15
            With tb_X
                .Height = 15
                .Width = 190
                .SpecialEffect = fmSpecialEffectFlat
                .Left = 5
                .Top = TopPos
                .Font.Size = 11
                .Text = tB_X.Font.Size  'just a test, to get the set font size
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

The Font.Size is being set to 11. But the text of some of the Textboxes is bigger then from others. If I set the size to 10 or 14 they all are the same, otherwise not. I tried playing with the `MultiLine`, `WordWrap` etc. without any success.

Do you have an explanation for this?

PS:
I know I could do this with a ListBox, but I want more options for the boxes like different background colors etc. to thats why I decided to use several textboxes rather then one listbox. As far as I know VBA is very limited in this direction.

Thank you!